# Can not insert data to the Table

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to upload data from ERP-system (1C Enterprise) to Google BigQuery table.
I'm using HTTP POST request as described here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/insertAll

I use the link: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/MyProjectId/datasets/1C/tables/Test_table/insertAll
where MyProjecId is like some-letters-6_digits
1C - is id of my data set
Test_table - is id of my table in 1C dataset

The table has 2 fields:
field1 - string - nullable
field2 - string - nullable
[image]

Headers: ...token... + "Content-Type=application/json"

Body:

```
{
 "kind": "bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest",
 "skipInvalidRows": false,
 "rows": [
  {
   "insertId": "1",
   "json": {
    "field1": "aaa",
    "field2": "bbbbbbbb"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

I reseive response 200 Ok, and data:
{
 "kind": "bigquery#tableDataInsertAllResponse"
}
[image]
but... no any rows appears in the table...

What I do wrong?